# Woocommerce: the shipping method is changed on checkout progress

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I did hide the shipping method from the cart checkout. The user will select the shipping method on cart page.

In the cart page I selected fedex:15:GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY as the shipping method.

On the checkout page, I can see the shipping rate.

When I press "Place order" button on the checkout page, it shown the Pickup as shipping method.

I checked the log file on

```
woocommerce_checkout_process:

2020-10-21 01:13:23: 

  $chosen_methods       = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );   
  $chosen_methods  = fedex:15:GROUND_HOME_DELIVERY
```

but

```
woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta:

2020-10-21 01:13:24

  $chosen_methods       = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );   
  $chosen_methods  = local_pickup
```

It is very strange.

and the shipping rate on the order page is 0 too.

please advice
Thanks

[image: 1]